# REGEX - Match something.something without something.css

Tags: regex, regex-negation

i know that my question has been already asked many times, but even with those other topics, i still can't solve my issue...

So the question is :
How can i just match this string : `something.something` without match anything like `something.css` `something.jpg` `something.png` etc... but this one have to match : `something.cssblabla`

What i have currently is something like that :

```
\w+.([^(css)|(png)|(jpg)]|\w+)
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use boundary

```
\w+[.](?!(css|png|jpg)\b)\w+
```

boundary would check(**not match**) for any non word character(anything except \w).Hence the name word boundary

Answer (score 2):

You need to use negative lookahead:

```
\w+\.(?!css\b)
```